# Is the Domino's Pizza Tracker actually patent pending?

Tags: patentability, software, pre-grant, patent-pending, consumer-food

4 years ago Domino's launched the "pizza tracker".  It has since then said "Patent Pending" on the tracker image.  Is this actually patent pending?  Any chance they would actually get the patent?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJOhc.jpg

Answer (score 6):

There's very good discussion here: http://www.techdirt.com/articles/20100315/0058408555.shtml - one of the comments:

> "Jim Vitek says on his LinkedIn profile that he is one of the named
>   inventors. Yet there's nothing on the PTO search site - I'm a patent
>   practitioner, and I looked. Assuming a provisional was filed in
>   January 2008, and an application filed in January 2009, then under the
>   18-month rule, this application should be published in a few months,
>   after which we'll be able to see what exactly was claimed."

you might need to search for the USPTO Patent # so you can know the updates on this.

UPDATE: Found it: http://www.google.com/patents/WO2001054478A2 and http://www.google.com/patents/US20030065565 you can ask for an update via:

https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/WO2001054478A2 and
https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/US20030065565

UPDATE 2:

For [US20030065565](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20030065565) the US Public Pair lists the application as abandoned as of 09-17-2007.

Comment: Hmm, if this is really the application for the pizza tracker, it was filed way back in 2000. According to the USPTO's [public Patent Application Information Retrieval (PAIR)](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) system, the patent office issued a final rejection of all claims in this application on 1 December 2006, and it was officially listed as abandoned on 18 September 2007. So this application never resulted in an issued patent. Interestingly, all of that happened several years before the [2010 article](https://www.techdirt.com/articles/20100315/0058408555.shtml) mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can now find the US Patent No. on the tacker. It's #[10262281](https://patents.google.com/patent/US10262281B1/)

[image: Domino's Track Screenshot]